# What is the process that I should follow to build an add-on from scratch?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I try to understand of how building an add-on for chrome and firefox web browser,
The idea is to display a notification or popup window on the page that the user open after fetch the title from JSON file or the user select the title of the website (I do not know what the better,advice me ! )and it's in JSON file

Comment: You mean an extension? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: yes thank you , Is there a simple example to see how it's work and write ?

Answer (score 0):

Building addons for firefox and chrome together is a little bit tricky. 
In Chrome you can start writing your [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) using only JavaScript.

For firefox, you have some choices to work with your plugin:

1. Using the `jpm` sdk for firefox addon developing. In [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)) you can find the get started plugin example, OR
2. Using [firefox web extensions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/lets_write_a_webextension/), which using no sdk and has similar API to chrome but it is new to firefox and they are not fully implemented.